# Java instancing classes to allow dynamic fields

Tags: java, performance, syntax, instance, instance-variables

I have been looking over some java projects and have seen this inconsistency between different developers/projects:

(PLEASE NOTE: For the below, only ONE Edibles will EVER exist, Edibles is NEVER required to have two active instances.)

Project 1:

```
public class Edibles1 {

    private final HashMap<Integer, Food> edibleFoods = new HashMap<>();

    private static final Edibles edibles = new Edibles();

    public static Edibles getEdibles() {
        return edibles;
    }

    //external usage for this project:
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Food foodForId = Edibles.getEdibles().edibleFoods.get(123);
        System.out.println(foodForId);

    }



}
```

Project 2:

```
public class Edibles2 {

    private static final HashMap<Integer, Food> edibleFoods = new HashMap<>();

    //external usage for this project:
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Food foodForId = Edibles.edibleFoods.get(123);
        System.out.println(foodForId);

    }



}
```

Please keep in mind that ONLY ONE Edibles#edibleFoods is EVER required by the project.

In the documentation, some developers who use edibles1 write that is it safer? Although maybe they just want to be consistent with their classes because even though only one Edibles is needed for the project, similar classes require multiple and therefore need example1.

So could it be that developers just want consistency or is there a deeper meaning/understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Project 1 is (partially) implementing the [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  By partially I mean that it should have a private constructor so that other classes can access the singleton only through the static `getEdibles()` method.

The Singleton design pattern is needed only if other classes need to access the Singleton class and interact with it (get/set values, invoke methods etc)

project 2 does not implement the Singleton DP.  the map is accessible only to methods of the class `Edibles2`

Comment: So if only Edibles needed to access edibleFoods field, then I should stick to project 2? Or does it not really matter; and is just up to preference?

Comment: Yes, you should apply the Singleton DP only if other classes need to interact with a sinlge instance of your class.